# HTML code from node js not interpreted as such by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webserver

I have created my first node js application: a simple webserver.
Here's the code:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("<a href=\"http://www.tagesschau.de/\">ARD Tagesschau</a>\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

When I connect to the server via my browser I get the full string specified in my code as a web page.

Shouldn't the browser interpret that HTML code and display a link? Why do I get the full HTML code shown as plain text?

Comment: Sound like you need to send headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have explicitly said that you are returning plain text, not HTML. The browser therefore treats it as plain text.

If you want HTML to be treated as HTML then say it *is* HTML:

```
{"Content-Type": "text/html"}
```

(Although you should send back an HTML document and not a fragment of HTML).

Answer (score 2):

Following Code works for me:

```
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.end("<a href=\"http://www.tagesschau.de/\">ARD Tagesschau</a>\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

You need to set the Headers. For more information check in [Node API docs here.](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

Check the difference in your firebug or dev tools to understand how browser interprets differently based on Header [Content-Type](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value).